# create a stored procwhich pulls all data from 3 tables in which 2 tables are having same column name and 3rd table having different column name

Tags: sql-server

Need to create a stored procedure which pulls all the data from three different tables in which two tables are having same column name and third table having different column name,

I have tried this,

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].XYZ  
    @ssn    VARCHAR(11)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT  *   
    FROM    ([dbo].[TBL_A]
    WHERE REPLACE(ssn,'-','')  =    @ssn

    UNION 

    SELECT  *   
    FROM    [dbo].[TBL_B]
    WHERE REPLACE(ssn,'-','')  =    @ssn

    UNION 

    SELECT  *   
    FROM     [dbo].[TBL_C]
    WHERE   (ssn_tin)   =   @ssn         

END
GO
```

Comment: First, what is your question?  As a comment, why create a stored procedure, as opposed to a function or view?

Comment: Names of the columns don't matter, but number of them and data types do. Also, anything with "select *" is bad idea, since then you can't be sure if you add a column to a table if it breaks something. Third, don't use functions for columns in where clause, that makes the select always scan the clustered index. If you need to do a replace, add a persistent computed column and index it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived query with your union and don't use `*`.

```
select x.field1, x.field2
  from (
    SELECT field1, field2   
    FROM    ([dbo].[TBL_A]
    WHERE REPLACE(ssn,'-','')  =    @ssn
    UNION 
    SELECT field1, field2
    FROM    [dbo].[TBL_B]
    WHERE REPLACE(ssn,'-','')  =    @ssn
    UNION 
    SELECT  field3, field4
    FROM     [dbo].[TBL_C]
    WHERE   (ssn_tin)   =   @ssn         
 ) x
```

Comment: Thanks for Response, but there are 100's of columns in each table and what is this 'x', is it equal to'@SSN'.

Comment: If I able to select x.field1, x.field2  , then wt about remaining columns?

Comment: x is an Alias...when you perform a union in a derived query like this it will assume that column1 is "field1" and column2 is "field2" so even if your 2nd and 3rd query have column names completely different as long as the `type` are the same it will use the column names from the first select.

Comment: Thanks for your Quick Response